# File was not uploaded!

Tags: magento-1.7, image-upload, varien-file-uploader

Recently I have applied patches on one of my Magento Website CE Version 1.7.0.2 till SUPEE 9652, Everything is running fine except a Custom Extension which I am using for inner page banners. It is giving me the error

> {"error":"File was not uploaded.","errorcode":666}

While file uploading, I have checked the Permissions and all, Product image upload is running perfectly fine, It was also running file till the Patch Application, Code skips TRY block on the first line and shows the error from Catch Block.

Here is my Upload Code:

```
public function uploadAction() {
    try {
        $uploader = new Mage_Core_Model_File_Uploader('image');
        $uploader->setAllowedExtensions(array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif', 'png'));
        $uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(true);
        $uploader->setFilesDispersion(true);
        $result = $uploader->save(
                        Mage::getSingleton('qbanner/config')->getBaseTmpMediaPath()
        );

        $result['tmp_name'] = str_replace(DS, "/", $result['tmp_name']);
        $result['path'] = str_replace(DS, "/", $result['path']);

        $result['url'] = Mage::getSingleton('qbanner/config')->getTmpMediaUrl($result['file']);
        $result['cookie'] = array(
            'name' => session_name(),
            'value' => $this->_getSession()->getSessionId(),
            'lifetime' => $this->_getSession()->getCookieLifetime(),
            'path' => $this->_getSession()->getCookiePath(),
            'domain' => $this->_getSession()->getCookieDomain()
        );
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        $result = array(
            'error' => $e->getMessage(),
            'errorcode' => $e->getCode());
    }
    $this->getResponse()->setBody(Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($result));
}
```

Please guide me on this issue, Thanks